# Thread works like method (update when finish)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, ui-thread

I have class which draws a line on main activity, this line used to set number. (if swipe changed number and length this line.)

So now I want make little animation when I set line on number. 
for example I open activity for first and I set "line" on number 6. So I want if open activity for second I want set "line" on number 6. (I have this) BUT i want little animation fast move from 0 to 6.

**Every of this method run.. But run wrong I want update UI (imageview in mainactivity) every 50ms but all of this examples update IF thread finish, so I don't see animation I see JUMP on number. it's wrong.**

And I write thise code //thread

```
 private void IntSkok(final int noci) {

   // int noci;                                  //how number I want set
    final int POCKROKOV=5;                       //steps between n and n+1
    final double[] hodnota = new double[1];      //how much px is one steps

    Thread timer = new Thread() { //new thread
        public void run() {
            Boolean b = true;
            try {
                do {
                    sleep(50);

                            while (hodnota[0] <(noci*34)) {

                                hodnota[0] = hodnota[0] + (34.0/POCKROKOV);
                                progresInt.prepisBol(hodnota[0]);   //this method set "line" on position I put int in px and thise method calculate number on this pozition and rewrite on mainactivity           
                                imgint=progresInt.Aktualizacia();  // this method is only imageview.invalidate();

                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(50);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                }
                while (b == true);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
        };
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

I put info in code

```
private void IntSkok(final int noci) {

   // int noci;
    final int POCKROKOV=5;
    final double[] hodnota = new double[1];

    Thread timer = new Thread() { //new thread
        public void run() {
            Boolean b = true;
            try {
                do {

                    sleep(50);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            while (hodnota[0] <(noci*34)) {

                                hodnota[0] = hodnota[0] + (34.0/POCKROKOV);
                                progresInt.prepisBol(hodnota[0]);
                                imgint=progresInt.Aktualizacia();
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(50);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    });


                }
                while (b == true);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
        };
    };
    timer.start();
}

private void IntSkok2(final int noci){
    //int noci;
    final int POCKROKOV=5;
    final double[] hodnota = new double[1];
 Thread   thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    wait(50);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            while (hodnota[0] <(noci*34)) {

                                hodnota[0] = hodnota[0] + (34.0/POCKROKOV);
                                progresInt.prepisBol(hodnota[0]);
                                imgint=progresInt.Aktualizacia();
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(50);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

Every of this method run.. But run wrong I want update UI (imageview in mainactivity) every 50ms but all of this examples update IF thread finish, so I don't see animation I see JUMP on number. it's wrong.

Internet tolod told me may try

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
```

but this work more wrong then my code, because this start my activity when finish thread.

Please do you have some ideas how solve my problem Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to block the ui thread in your way. When you want to you runOnUiThread, just do something relevant with UI.

I think this change is gonna work.

```
    Thread timer = null;
    private void IntSkok(final int noci) {

        // int noci; //how number I want set
        final int POCKROKOV = 5; // steps between n and n+1
        final double[] hodnota = new double[1]; // how much px is one steps
        timer = new Thread() { // new thread
            public void run() {
                Boolean b = true;
                try {
                    do {
                        sleep(50);
                        while (hodnota[0] < (noci * 34)) {
                            hodnota[0] = hodnota[0] + (34.0 / POCKROKOV);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    progresInt.prepisBol(hodnota[0]);
                                    progresInt.Aktualizacia();
                                }

                            });
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(50);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                    } while (b == true);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
```

Comment: this doing nothing, i don't know why.

Comment: Did you user timer.start()? I didn't add that method call there.

Comment: Sorry, no 

Now good good, I little modify code for better function, thanks. (y)